# media query for html button

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

Hi I want to align both the button horizontally on same line in media screen. Please help me with css. Following is the code that I am trying.

```
    <div class="ctext-wrap">
      <button type="button" class="btn offert-btn btn-next">Mer information<br></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous offert-btn">Föregående<br></button>
    </div>

    .ctext-wrap {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .ctext-wrap {
        max-width: 50%;
        margin: 0px auto;
        text-align: left;
    }


    .btn-next {
        float: right;
        min-width: 130px;
    }

    .offert-btn {
        display: inline-block;
        background: #213156 !important;
        color: #fff !important;
        font-weight: bold !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
        margin-bottom: 20px !important;
        border-radius: 0 !important;
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
.ctext-wrap {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Which screen size you want button in same line?

Comment: screen size: 768px

Answer (score 2):

This CSS work below 768px.

Use this fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0x0rnkob/)

Added this CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.ctext-wrap .btn {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `display:flex` in `.ctext-wrap` and `justify-content: space-between;`.

I will make what you want without using media query.

```
.ctext-wrap {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8jq06wod/1/)**

Comment: display: flex;  partial support for browsers right?

Comment: @VIVEKRAJ `display:flex` support in all latest browser so far. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Ok,one more doubt.how the display:flex works without the media queries?

Comment: `display:flex` have functionality for which you don't need to use media query for some task. like in this question. You can read more about it in given above link in commnet